# Convert exception to string in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, python-unicode

```
import httplib

webservice = httplib.HTTPSConnection(host)
# ....
try:
    webservice.endheaders()
except Exception, exc:
    handle_failure(request, exc_str=unicode(exc))
```

The exception contains:

> error(110, 'Die Wartezeit f\xc3\xbcr die Verbindung ist abgelaufen')

Don't ask me why this message is in German.

The `uncode(exc)` fails like this:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 27:
                     ordinal not in range(128)
```

What is the failsafe way to convert an exception to a string in Python 2.7?

Definition of failsafe in this context: I must not get a UnicodeError. The expection goes to the logs. It is ok if non-ascii characters get lost.

Comment: Is there any reason you have to use `unicode` and can't just `exc_str=str(exc)`?

Comment: Try by simply typecasting the exception to `str` using `str(exc)`

Comment: You would `.decode` if you wanted a unicode string, it looks like you already have a utf-8 encoded string so not sure why you want to change it. using `unicode(s)` will try to use ascii encoding, you would use `unicode(s,"utf-8")`, decode as already mentioned or just use the string as is

Answer (score 0):

Add `errors='replace'` or `errors='ignore'` parameter to the `unicode` function.

The following text is from [this](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#the-unicode-type) documentation:

> The `errors` argument specifies the response when the input string can’t
>   be converted according to the encoding’s rules. Legal values for this
>   argument are ‘strict’ (raise a `UnicodeDecodeError` exception),
>   ‘replace’ (add U+FFFD, ‘REPLACEMENT CHARACTER’), or ‘ignore’ (just
>   leave the character out of the Unicode result). The following examples
>   show the differences:
>
> ```
> $ unicode('\x80abc', errors='strict')     
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> ...
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0:
> ordinal not in range(128)
> $ unicode('\x80abc', errors='replace')
> u'\ufffdabc'
> $ unicode('\x80abc', errors='ignore')
> u'abc'
> ```

Comment: @PadraicCunningham The OP did ask for a failsafe way, if they don't know the encoding then it might be safer to do this. But mgn should probably note that this causes data loss.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I updated the question. Definition of failsafe in this context: I must not get a UnicodeError. The expection goes to the logs. It is ok if non-ascii characters get lost.

Comment: @guettli, why are you using unicode at all? Do you not know what the encoding is going to be?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Why I use `unicode(exc)`? Since I want to write the string to a file. I know the encoding of the output I want to create. But I don't know the garbage which is in the exception. The exception is not from my code.

Comment: @guettli,  what you see is a utf-8 encoded string, if the data is coming from the same source it is most likely all utf-8 encoded which you can write to a file no problem, you are only see errors as you are trying to decode to ascii using the default value for the `unicode` function

Comment: @PadraicCunningham this time it is utf-8. Next time it can be a different encoding.

Comment: @guettli, if you don't care the output why not just do something like log the reason, status etc..?

Answer (score 0):

`unicode` and `str` conversions assume the default ASCII encoding. And they are not Python3 compatible (it may not be a concern now but become later).

My advice is to use `decode` method to generate unicode from a Python2 string and `encode` to generate a Python2 string from unicode. This of course using your local encoding, and optionnaly adding `errors = 'replace'` if you want it to be immune to encoding/decoding errors.

Here, you should write:

```
except Exception, exc:
    handle_failure(request, exc_str=exc.decode('utf8', errors='replace')
```

On my system, with your example it gives: `Die Wartezeit für die Verbindung ist abgelaufen`